# How to list grandchildren PIDs of target PID from a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

Write a script which displays the PID's of all the grandchildren of the process whose PID is given as an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

function display_cpid()
{
    child_pids=`pgrep -P $1 | xargs`
    for child_pid in $child_pids;
    do
    echo "$child_pid"
    display_cpid $child_pid
    done
}
display_cpid $1
```

That's my work. It prints children of a process which PID is taken as argument, but I want to print only grandchildren.

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with. Add a "depth" argument, increment on entry and recurse til it's value is 2 then print. If that's not all you need then [edit] your question to clarify where you need help.

Comment: It sounds like a recursion problem in Bash. @Ed's comment sounds about right.

Comment: This function prints children of a process, in which the PID is taken as an argument. I wan to print only grandchildren processes.

Comment: I didn't understand what you told me. Can you please edit my code in the right way. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a "depth" argument, increment on entry and recurse til it's value is 2 then print. If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify where you need help.

```
#!/bin/env bash

display_cpid() {
    local depth=$1 pid=$2 child_pid
    (( ++depth ))
    while IFS= read -r child_pid; do
        if (( depth < 2 )); then
            display_cpid "$depth" "$child_pid"
        else
            echo "$child_pid"
        fi
    done < <(pgrep -P "$pid" | xargs)
}

display_cpid 0 "$1"
```

Comment: Could you please edit my code in the right way because i cant understand what you said.

Comment: OK, done. I cleaned up some other things while I was adding the depth argument. idk if `pgrep ... | xargs` is the best way to do whatever you're doing with that command but I left it alone as I don't have pgrep on my machine to test with.

Comment: You think that there is a better way to solve this? If yes please help me.

Comment: Idk what more help you'd need/want. If you have a new question then post it as such.